# MySQL Error for Mac OSx

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I'm trying to run the mysql command on my mac osx but keep getting the error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I did try researching this extensively but could'nt find a suitable solution. Most of the solutions refer to /etc/my.cnf but I don't seem to have this configuration file in the first place. I'm pretty much stuck and have been for quite a while. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: uh, why did this 1 guy vote to close? this is a genuine problem i'm facing and badly need help. i don't see this as an being off-topic and am greatly appreciative of any help.

Comment: Now you have 2 guys vote to close. This is not a deadly problem, google, please?

Comment: 'I did try researching this extensively'. He's obviously tried googling it. This is the point of StackOverflow I thought, find answers that google can't? I upvoted the question for ya ;)

Comment: Voted to close, because this question belongs on ServerFault.com, not on stackoverflow. People on SF should be able to help you better than we can.

Comment: @Rob much appreciated mate. life's hard for a newbie here it seems...

Comment: How was MySQL installed? Homebrew? Binaries?

Comment: @ace i used the .dmg files and followed the instructions from there using the GUI.

Comment: Did you check `/tmp` to see if `mysql.sock` exists?

Comment: it does not exist. so i guess i gotta make it?

Comment: Yes, here's a guide to help you. And careful of the user permissions, it's best to run it as mysql user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-ma/5140849#5140849

Comment: @all ops ... http://www.google.com.sg/search?q=Can't+connect+to+local+MySQL+server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to ajreal's answer, check the "obvious" stuff...a lot of times you'll get this error when MySQL server isn't running, or you don't have permission to access it. Check in your process list to make sure it's running, seeing something like...

```
$ ps -ef |grep mysql
root      5325     1  0 13:09 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql     5413  5325  0 13:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-external-locking --port=3306 --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
root      5415  5325  0 13:09 ?        00:00:00 logger -p daemon.err -t mysqld_safe -i -t mysqld
```

If you don't have permissions, try the command  `sudo chmod 775 /var/lib/mysql` to elevate your permissions.

Or if it IS running, you may need to reinstall (yikes) but if you don't have much time, and scratching it is an option, use it as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

1. check exist of socket /tmp/mysql.sock
2. check mysql daemon is running
3. check is it using / listening on port only

*this could be serverfault area*

```
ps afx | grep mysql   <--- this will show the mysql daemon command, 
                           you can make use of the information returned
```